# How to have multiple colors with a single material on a single object?

Tags: texturing, materials, blenderkit

For context, I am using Blenderkit materials here. So, I have a wall, which i have divided in two parts, the top and bottom one.
[image]

My goal is to use the same material but change the color of the bottom part, similar to what's happening here.

[image]

How would i achieve this? The problem I'm running into is that if i try to create a new material and assign it to the bottom part, once I drag in the same material from Blenderkit, both become connected, so changing the bottom's color will change the top one aswell.

[image]

[image]

Here is the node setup for the material. Would appreciate some help as i run into this problem quite often!

[image]

Here's the file:
[image]

Edit for MoonBoots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: As you material is UV based, it mainly depends on how the UV map is projected on the surface. Could you show it?

Comment: I edited the post but I'm not sure that's what you want me to show you. I can share the file via google doc if it's easier for you

Comment: Yes but please prefer this link for uploading: https://blend-exchange.com/ (dont't forget to pack the texture)

Comment: I edited the post with the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is simply to test the height, tuning two comparison nodes (greater and less than).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

sorry for my very bad English :D.
You can also use on Empty objet to create the reference for the color change.
and mixte this color with your color matériel slot.
It's to simplify your problem and give you un easy solution, But it's a strange bug for me ^^.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use this node set-up:

- A: control the gradient height
- B: control the top color
- C: control the bottom color
- D: another way to adjust the gradient

[image: nodes]

It looks like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the given answers, use the *Generated* output of the *Texture Coordinate*, plug it into a *Separate XYZ*, use it as a factor in a *Mix Color* in *Multiply* mode:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly that setup isn't working for me, even though everything seems to be in order. I'll update the post with the node setup so you can take a look if you want!

Comment: maybe apply the rotation of your object in Object mode?

Comment: Still not working :/ One of the suggestions above ended up working for me, but regardless, the file is available in the post in case you want to take a look

Comment: Could you please share the file with my solution?

Comment: Done, thanks for taking a look

Comment: Yes, that's weird, I'm trying to understand, I can't make the Generated work, have modeled the object in Blender?

Comment: The object was modelled by myself. The texture comes from Blenderkit tho, so that might be causing some issues somehow